# Create a process without elevation

Tags: c#, uac, elevation

I want to create a child process in my application that will run not inherit the parent's UAC. The parent runs as administrator, and I want the child process to a run as a simple user w/o elevation.
Does anyone know how this can be done?

I'm coding in c#.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Very simple:

```
string appWithoutElevation = @"c:\some  foldre\app.exe";
Process.Start("explorer", appWithoutElevation);
```

Comment: This seems to work. Just bit puzzled why this is so easy. Does creates any side effects ?

Comment: Raymon Chen wrote 2x articles about this ([first](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20131118-00/?p=2643), [second](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20190425-00/?p=102443)) and in the second article he makes certain to mention that if the user is an administrator and UAC is disabled, then explorer.exe will still be elevated.